# Microsoft Unity: Interception not working when using BuildUp instead of Resolve

Tags: c#, unity-container, unity-interception

I am using Microsoft Unity 2.0 and the interception extension is not working as expected.

Consider these two lines of code:

```
MyUnityContainer.Configure<Interception>().SetDefaultInterceptorFor<MyType>(new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
var someObject = MyUnityContainer.BuildUp<MyType>(anObject);
```

These two lines don't get you the dynamic proxy you'd expect for someObject! How can one make interception work for such a scenario?

Comment: The same problem applies to Unity 1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff646991.aspx) explains that you cannot use virtual interception using `BuildUp` since it can only be applied when the object is created (since a subclass of the target object is dynamically generated):

> Interception only happens on virtual
>   methods. You must set up interception
>   at object creation time and cannot
>   intercept an existing object.

Comment: Is there any way to intercept existing intstances without making them cloneable? Maybe a custom object creator?

Answer (score 0):

VirtualMethodInterceptor works only on new objects. You could use the Interface or TransparentProxy interceptors instead to intercept an existing instance (since those use explicit proxy objects).

I could see possibly adding a VirtualMethodProxyInterceptor, but I expect it'd just cause more confusion than help.